# Defining a mySql result as a variable for a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am wondering if this is possible. I know this is hardly practical...I did though, run into a case where this might come in handy.

Take this example, straight forward.

```
while( $row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){}
```

Now, can something like this be done?

```
$newVar = '$row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)';
while($newVar){}
```

I have tried many ways but to no avail.

My while loops print out a lot of data and depending on the type of query/connection (mySql, mySqli, or PDO) would depend on what statement goes into the while loop.

This is somewhat my fallback idea if prepared statements are not supported.

Comment: *"Now, can this be done?"* - Have you tried it?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the case where you think this could come in handy? Odds are, there's a more natural approach to it.

Comment: Haha, yes, in many variations with no luck.

Comment: I'm working on a fallback to some PDO statements, and `$newVar` could be either for a `mySql` `mySqli` or `PDO` result.

Comment: Theoretically `while($newVar){}` could work but will give you an endless loop. You'll need to add something to it in order to make it stop onces it reaches a certain limit.

Comment: Downvoter..If you are smarter than this question, then just answer it and stop being a jerk. I ask and answer many useful questions on here. Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: @RyanPendleton I added a little more detail to my question if you would have a look.

Comment: What exactly have you tried (you mention "I have tried many ways but to no avail"... what are these ways?). What exactly is your question?

Comment: @AndyJones Well, I did NOT try what Ryan answered. It's exactly what I was looking for. A much better approach than what I was doing. Thanks for taking a look at my question though! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function to fetch a row is different, you may be able to use closures depending on the PHP version you are using. To use closures, you would want to define a function that knows how to fetch a row, then you can pass it to your while loop. For example, here are closures for PDO and MySQL:

```
$pdo_fetch = function() use ($qry)
{
    return $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$mysql_fetch = function() use ($result)
{
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

These closures can come from anywhere, then passed into your while loop:

```
if($pdo)
{
    $fetch = $pdo_fetch;
}
else
{
    $fetch = $mysql_fetch;
}

while($row = $fetch()) { }
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I hear you about the "string", I tried many other ways as well. The question was more general.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I threw an if/else statement in the function you posted to decide what to return and it works great. Brilliant approach!

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 No, my original database connection first tries using a prepared statement, and if it fails, it falls back to a standard mysql statement. From then on, each query string has to be built differently, so I need to do an if(PDO)else(mySql) then run the While Loop based on the original connection type.

Comment: @VIDesignz You are probably doing this already, but I just want to make sure. You can do do your if-else outside of the closure. That way, you don't have to check for each row fetch. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @RyanPendleton Wow, that's nifty. Sooo slick. Works great. Will the `use ($result)` be redefined every time I define it from a new query? Meaning its a one time function declaration? I assume yes but I never used `use ()` before.

Comment: @VIDesignz `use ()` basically tells the interpreter that you want to use the `$result` variable from the same scope the function is defined in. Unless you're defining the closure for each query, you'll want to make it a function argument instead.

Comment: Got it, same scope it is!